# Paypal localized from shipping country

Tags: php, paypal, localization, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm implementing Paypal rest API for one of my customers and I'm facing an issue.

My merchant platform is a French Guiana based business so everything should be in French, but when customers put French Guiana in the form for country, I'm providing GF as ISO 2 Country code and the PayPal interface is in English... is there a way to force the French language? Moreover, if I try to put FRANCE as country from a France located computer, the page is translated in french AND I can process to the payment without opening a PayPal account, which is not possible in the French Guiana case.

Is there some kind of geolocalization of PayPal for language and features selection OR it's all based on the country code in the shipping address... (but regarding the tests I did, it appears that the country iso code 2 provided during the transaction is not enough to force proper PayPal interface.

I saw this in the documentation :

> Pass a locale code to PayPal to customize the locale of the buyer's checkout experience.
>
> To determine the locale for the checkout page, PayPal uses the locale code and these other factors:
>
> - The shipping address country provided by the merchant in the request.
> - The country was taken from the locale code parameter passed by the merchant.
> - The country of the currently logged-in user.
> - The merchant's country.
> - When this information is not available, PayPal uses these default locales in this order:
>
>   - en_US
>   - fr_XC
>   - es_XC
>   - zh_XC

In the documentation, but after a test, it seems to not be working just with the `FR` shippingCountryCode... (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/locale-codes/)

Help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using /Payments API for your Checkout  ( looks like you are )

Look at the below object - and pass the appropriate locale.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-application_context

The other bit is that the locale is also dependent on the buyer preferences - for e.g. you might have someone in French Guyana but who has chosen english as the language.

use a locale of "fr-GF" this should do the trick.

if for some reason you are using an SDK that doesn't yet support application_context than you will have to recourse to using the Payments Experience API - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/ look at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#definition-presentation for a similar capability .